# One to many relation getting recent records plus one column from previous record

Tags: sql-server

Table 1

```
ProductID   Status
PD_1       OPN
PD_2       CLS
```

Table2

```
Table2_id   ProductID   Amount 
1           PD_1        900
2           PD_1        800
3           PD_2        1000
4           PD_2        900
5           PD_2        700
```

Final expected result

```
ProductID   Recent_Amount   Previous_Amount   Status 
PD_1        900             800               OPN
PD_2        1000            900               CLS
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the previous row value for a column using the [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function and limit to the most recent row using [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
SELECT ProductId,
  RecentAmount,
  PreviousAmount,
  Status
FROM
(
SELECT
  t1.ProductId,
  t2.Amount AS RecentAmount,
  LAG(t2.Amount, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY t2.ProductId ORDER BY t2.Id ASC) AS PreviousAmount,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.ProductId ORDER BY t2.Id DESC) AS Rn,
  t1.Status
FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN Table1 t1 ON t1.ProductId = t2.ProductId
) t
WHERE Rn = 1
```

Your example data is a little confusing though. For PD_2, your expected results indicate that 1000 is the most recent amount and 900 the previous amount, however, the 1000 record has a lower Id value the 900 record. Typically, one would assume the higher Id value records were entered alter than the lower ones.

In any case, you can see a working example of the LAG function, combined with ROW_NUMBER to pick the single row [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=94185459cd224a38d2fb899a4b826982). This example uses specific ordering in the LAG (DESC) and ROW_NUMBER (ASC) functions to return your expected resultset.

If your example data is incorrect and the 1000 record should actually be a higher Id value, you can change the LAG and ROW_NUMBER functions from

```
LAG(t2.Amount, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY t2.ProductId ORDER BY t2.Id DESC) AS PreviousAmount,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.ProductId ORDER BY t2.Id ASC) AS Rn,
```

to

```
LAG(t2.Amount, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY t2.ProductId ORDER BY t2.Id ASC) AS PreviousAmount,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.ProductId ORDER BY t2.Id DESC) AS Rn,
```

as shown in [this example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8dec31b7d51e1f26bf205f30b6095239).